# I get a kernel error

Tags: system-installation

Can someone, please, tell me what to do to fix this error?

[image: kernel error]

Answer (score 2):

You must download 32-bit iso...Take a look at  [Ubuntu alternative downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads).